# add letter to input with v-model

Tags: vuejs2

I need to add a letter in input always to begin with '&' this input has v-model that not related to the data in v-model
so for example the input value will have to start always with & then some string that is coming from the v-model. the input might already has the & in the beginning and if not will have to be added
example:
input has
v-model='helllo'
value in the input needs to be : &hello

i tried to use value='andText' but it doesn't seem to do the trick where andtext='&'

Comment: Add a listener to input field `@keydown="foo($event)"` then do whatever inside the foo function

Comment: no good. I need this to appear regardless of keydown

Comment: Sorry, your phrasing is a bit confusing to me. Are you expecting a user to always see '&hello'? Or are you expecting to be able to append an '&' for other purposes, such as an API call? It would be helpful if you showed some attempted code so we can see how you're using the appended-to-variable